# How to change mailling url for staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I created new staging environment by using fork command to my production server. Now for user registration i sent mail to user for authentication , now for staging server how can i change that mailing url. In my case on staging server mailing address is still of my production server.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "example.com" }
```

Set a default host that will be used in all mailers by setting the :host option as a configuration option in `config/application.rb` refer this link (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)

Comment: how can it work in staging environment , in my config/environment/production.rb i added if Rails.env == "production"
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'getpayad.herokuapp.com' }
  else
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'getpayad-staging.herokuapp.com' }
  end 

but issue is even in staging environment is still production.

Comment: U have to configure custom `ENV` for your application refer this link its should help you (https://richonrails.com/articles/creating-a-custom-rails-environment)

Answer (score 1):

You can create the file: `config/initializers/action_mailer.rb` with following contents:

```
# config/initializers/action_mailer.rb
if Rails.env.development?

  # Settings for mailcatcher on dev enviroment
  Rails.application.config.action_mailer.tap do |action_mailer|
    action_mailer.default_url_options = {
        host: 'dev-domain.dev',
        port: 3000
    }

    action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
    action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: "localhost", port: 1025 }
  end
end

if Rails.env.production?
  # Define settings for Production SMTP Server
  Rails.application.config.action_mailer.tap do |action_mailer|
    action_mailer.default_url_options = {
        host: 'production-domain.com'
    }

    action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        address: 'mail.server.com',
        port: '465',
        authentication: :plain,
        user_name: 'noreply@production-domain.com',
        password: '',
        domain: 'production-domain.com',
        enable_starttls_auto: false,
        ssl: true
    }
  end
end

if Rails.env.staging?
  # Define settings for Staging SMTP Server
  Rails.application.config.action_mailer.tap do |action_mailer|
    action_mailer.default_url_options = {
        host: 'staging-domain.com'
    }

    action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        address: 'mail.staging-server.com',
        port: '465',
        authentication: :plain,
        user_name: 'noreply@staging-domain.com',
        password: '',
        domain: 'staging-domain.com',
        enable_starttls_auto: false,
        ssl: true
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use an environment variable for the application's URL as explained [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), e.g. APPLICATION_URL = 'http://foo.herokuapp.com' in production environment and APPLICATION_URL = 'http://foo-staging.herokuapp.com' in staging environment. You can then use different URLs in different environments, by using these environment variables in your code.

Comment: please explain your answer.

Comment: I've added more contents. Hope that makes sense.